# Multiple pages pdf using jspdf

Tags: html, image, electron, jspdf

I'm a Javascript beginner and for a desktop application (using electron) I'm trying to gather the content of several divs (only images jpeg) to create a pdf when the user clicks on the "download" button.

I've got this HTML code :

```
<div class="flipbook" id="flipbook">
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/8.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/9.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/11.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/12.jpg"></div>
    <div class="page"><img src="pages/13.jpg"></div>
    ...
</div>

<button onclick="downloadContent()" type="button" 
class="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" 
id="download" title="Télécharger le fichier"></span></button>
```

And I would like to catch each  content (the jpg image) and generate a pdf "onClick" with one image per page. The image size should be "A4" just like the pdf file. I can not covert jpeg file into data url as it is asked here https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html#, because I don't want to use an external url in my app. So I use html2canvas.

Javascript :

```
function downloadContent() {
var flipbook = getElementById('flipbook');
    for (var i = 0; i = flipbook.length; i++) {
        html2canvas('.page'); {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
                doc.save('My_doc.pdf');
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Or

```
 function downloadContent() {
        html2canvas(getElementById('#flipbook'); {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
                doc.save('My_doc.pdf');
            }
        });

    }

 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Could you explain it?

Comment: My javascript code doesn't work. I would like to catch the image content of several divs and generate a pdf file when I click on a "download" button. But  I can't get that.